# Be successful vs good luck

Tags: differences, expression-choice

Does it sound right to say "be successful" instead of "good luck" as a quick reply? For instance:

> A : I have a tough exam tomorrow.
>
> B : I hope you'll be successful in your exam.

I suppose using "be successful" as a part of a sentence sounds right, but isn't it kind of awkward or unnatural to say "be successful" as a short reply instead of "good luck"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Be successful" sounds like a **command** - like you are ordering them to succeed.  Contrast this with "Good luck!", which means "I hope that you have good luck!".  In the latter you're not telling them what to do, you're describing something about **yourself**: offering some support, basically, which is rarely unwelcome.

You could say "I hope you are successful!", and while this is not a command, it does sound rather awkward.  I can't quite put my finger on why.  I would be inclined to say "I hope it goes well!", if you don't want to say "Good luck!".

Similarly, "I hope you pass!" sounds even more awkward to my ears: possibly because it raises the possibility that they might **not** pass, ie that **they might fail**, and bringing this up may be unwelcome - they probably don't want to think about failing.  This may be the reason that "I hope you are successful!" sounds awkward: it may be too similar to "I hope you don't fail!".

Talking about "luck", or it "going well", on the other hand, don't seem to raise the spectre of failure so much: perhaps because even if you are not lucky with the questions you may still pass, if you're well prepared.

Anyway, short answer: just say "Good luck!".

Comment: I don't think `I hope you pass!` sounds bad. I dislike `I hope you are successful` because of the formality, though. `I hope it goes well` is probably the best alternative to `good luck`